# css height 100% does not honor the background color on slide/show in jquery

Tags: css

i have this code:

```
<div id="left">
    <div>text</div>
    <p>
        text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br> text<br>
    </p>
</div>
```

js:

```
$('div').click(function() {
    $('p').show();
});
```

and css:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
#left {
    background: red;
 height: 100%;   
    width: 200px;
}
p { display: none; }
```

-- http://jsfiddle.net/AfRH2/1/

now, when you click on "text" the "p" should appear with its text. why my background color does not work? i want the div to expand with the color

[image]

Comment: "when you click on "text" the "p" should appear with its text"... it does. "why my background color does not work?"... what do you mean? " i want the div to expand with the color".... which div??

Comment: yes but the background color does not follow, view the image

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to add the `height: auto` or `height: auto !important` and the `min-height: 100%;`

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
#left {
    background: red;
    height: auto !important;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
}
p { display: none; }
```

see the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AfRH2/7/

Answer (score 5):

If you remove the `height: 100%` then you don't get the red background before all the text is shown. Change it to `min-height: 100%` and it solves your issue (at least it does in the fiddle).

Comment: this is great but this menu has to be 100% height because its on the left side of the page. and this is dynamic, sometimes i have a lot of items, sometimes i have 2 or 3. - as you can see in mine http://jsfiddle.net/AfRH2/1/

Answer (score 0):

Take the `height:100%;` off of the `#left` div.

Comment: Or you change it to "min-height:100%;" depending on what you want